# contains with separate result for each of multiple patterns

Tags: string, matlab

Matlab's documentation for the function `TF = contains(str,pattern)` states:

> If pattern is an array containing multiple patterns, then contains returns 1 if it finds any element of pattern in str.

I want a result for each pattern individually however. 
That is:

I have string `A='a very long string'` and two patterns `B='very'` and `C='long'`. I want to check if `B` is contained in `A` and if `C` is contained in `A`. I could do it like this:

```
result = false(2,1);
result(1) = contains(A,B);
result(2) = contains(A,C);
```

but for many patterns this takes quite a while. What is the fast way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know or have access to that function; it must be "new", so I don't know its particular idiosyncrasies.

How I would do that is:

```
result = ~cellfun('isempty', regexp(A, {B C}));
```

**EIDT**

Judging from [the documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contains.html), you can do the exact same thing with `contains`:

```
result = contains(A, {B C});
```

except that seems to return `contains(A,B) || contains(A,C)` rather than the array `[contains(A,B)  contains(A,C)]`. So I don't know, I can't test it here. But if all else fails, you can use the `regex` solution above.

Comment: thanks, the regexp expression seems to work and is quite a bit faster compared to calling contains multiple times.

Comment: The documentation you linked to is confusing, but I don't think the usage you've proposed actually works in the way the question asks it to: that will return 1 for each element in `A` that contains either `B` or `C`, but won't tell you which one was the match.  The regexp is a better choice.

Comment: @tmpearce yes, what I understood is exactly what you said, and what I wrote in the last paragraph -- for a single string `A` it returns a single true/false representing whether *any* of the patterns given were found in that string. Strange choice, that's not the use-case I usually encounter. Oh well.

Comment: I agree, it is strange; I don't often care if *any* of various strings match, I care *which* of the strings match.  I'm guessing it was a dimensionality problem: since arrays of any dimension can be passed in as the first argument, and also as the second argument, the formatting of the output could get quite confusing with high-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The new text processing functions in 16b are the fastest with string. If you convert A to a string you may see much better performance.

```
function profFunc

    n = 1E6;

    A = 'a very long string';
    B = 'very';
    C = 'long';

    tic;
    for i = 1:n
        result(1) = contains(A,B);
        result(2) = contains(A,C);
    end
    toc;

    tic;
    for i = 1:n
        x = regexp(A, {B,C});
    end
    toc;

    A = string(A);

    tic;
    for i = 1:n
        result(1) = contains(A,B);
        result(2) = contains(A,C);
    end
    toc;
end

>> profFunc
Elapsed time is 7.035145 seconds.
Elapsed time is 9.494433 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.930393 seconds.
```

Questions: Where do B and C come from? Do you have a lot of hard coded variables? Can you loop? Looping would probably be the fastest. Otherwise something like

```
cellfun(@(x)contains(A,x),{B C})
```

is an option.